# sample() producing multiple numbers when size of vector=1 in R

Tags: r, sample

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sampling in R from vector of varying length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990125/sampling-in-r-from-vector-of-varying-length)

I have a vector `a=5`
and would like to use the sample function `sample(a)`.
To my surprise this does not always return the number 5 but sometimes 4,3, etc.

What am I missing?