# Sample from vector of varying length (including 1)

Tags: r

I have a vector with varying length, which can sometimes be of length 1.

I would like to sample from this vector such that if its length is 1 it always samples that 1 number.

`sample()` won't do this because it samples from 1 to the digit when sample size is 1.

Comment: The answer for this question is the help file for `sample` see `?sample` and read carefully the 'Details' section, here you can find `If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x.`

Comment: and is there any way os making it sample only that single value?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a documented feature:

> If `x` has length `1`, is `numeric` (in the sense of `is.numeric`) and `x >= 1`, sampling via sample takes place from `1:x`. Note that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour when `x` is of varying length in calls such as `sample(x)`.

An alternative is to write your own function to avoid the feature:

```
sample.vec <- function(x, ...) x[sample(length(x), ...)]
sample.vec(10)
# [1] 10
sample.vec(10, 3, replace = TRUE)
# [1] 10 10 10
```

Some functions with similar behavior are listed under [seq vs seq_along. When will using seq cause unintended results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732062/seq-vs-seq-along-when-will-using-seq-cause-unintended-results/13732373#comment18871091_13732373)

Comment: We posted the same answer at the same moment apparently. Hence I moved my answer to the other identical question and voted to close-merge both questions.

Comment: Thanks @Joris. I thought my answer had a little more than yours so feel free to salvage if you agree. I would rather have closed the newer one but I don't know if there is a policy in place in such cases.

Comment: I've upvoted yours already :). I flagged the question for merging, so when that happens all answers are added together. I meant to close the other, but apparently I clicked "vote to close" in the wrong window. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 21):

When fed only one single number, `sample` works like `sample.int` (see `?sample`). If you want to make sure it only samples from the vector you give it, you can work with indices and use this construct:

```
x[sample(length(x))]
```

This gives you the correct result regardless the length of `x`, and without having to add an `if`-condition checking the length.

Example:

```
mylist <- list(
  a = 5,
  b = c(2,4),
  d = integer(0)
)

mysample <- lapply(mylist,function(x) x[sample(length(x))])

> mysample
$a
[1] 5

$b
[1] 2 4

$d
integer(0)
```

Note : you can replace `sample` by `sample.int` to get a little speed gain.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this 'bugfree' redefinition of the function:

```
sample = function(x, size, replace = F, prob = NULL) {
  if (length(x) == 1) return(x)
  base::sample(x, size = size, replace = replace, prob = prob)
}
```

Test it:

```
> sapply(1:7, base::sample, size = 1)
[1] 1 2 2 4 4 4 4
> sapply(1:7, sample)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resample()` from the gdata package. This saves you having to redefine resample in each new script. As calling `library(gdata)` masks a few functions and comes up with a few messages, you may consider using the double colon notation to call with `gdata::resample()`.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdata/versions/2.18.0/topics/resample