# Trying to simulate Deal or No Deal in R

Tags: r

I've looked through here to find a solution to my question, but I didn't see one.

In R, I'm trying to simulate *Deal or No Deal* for a project that gets us familiar with the software. I planned for this to be one big for loop but I can't get my second for loop to work. I broke it apart to make it easier to read (and for me to debug/test).

This loop simulates our original case picked that we keep throughout the game.

```
    for(i in 1){
    cases <- 1:26
    originalpick <- sample(cases, 1, replace = FALSE) #choose a case
    casesremaining <- (length(cases) - 1) #subtract original case from cases
    }
```

This loop simulates our first case picked to play.

```
    for(i in 1){
    casepicked <- replicate(1,sample(cases[-c(originalpick)], 1, replace = FALSE))
   }
```

My problem is that I am stuck with the possibility that I can choose my original case again. I used sample because I could turn replace off for this very reason, and since that didn't work, I thought that replicate would help. I have seen the update function but I cannot seem to get that to work either.

This is essentially the game, because I have to pick cases until I am left with 2 cases (originally picked case and the one left from cases variable).

I am still fairly new to R, so it could be just my misunderstanding of the functions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sampling from `cases[-originalpick]`, as you've done, prevents the `originalpick` from being sampled again. Do you mean that in your second loop (which, presumably, will be `for(i in seq_len(casesremaining))`), the `casepicked` is not omitted from subsequent draws?

Comment: Maybe you just want `cases <- 1:26; picks <- sample(cases)`, where `picks` is a permutation of `cases` and represents the order in which cases were picked. The first number in `picks` is the case that is kept throughout. Wrap that all in `replicate` if necessary.

Comment: @jbaums yes. however, i didn't think of the `for(i in seq_len(casesremaining))` because its going to be inside the other for loop.

Comment: @jbaums i tried `casepicked != cases` just to see if it accounted for the first pick and it didn't. Was I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: Depends on the context. It would help if you were to edit your question and give a more complete example. `casepicked != cases` will just return a logical vector with 26 elements, where elements are `FALSE` if their value matches `casepicked` and `TRUE` otherwise. Useful functions here might include `%in%` and `setdiff`, but I'm not convinced you need to do it iteratively anyway (see my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934741/trying-to-simulate-deal-or-no-deal-in-r#comment47991676_29934741)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to simulate the order in which cases are picked, you can do this with a single call to `sample` (wrapped in `replicate` if you want to perform multiple simulations).

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
cases <- 1:26
picks <- sample(cases)

picks
## [1]  7 10 14 21  5 19 23 13 12  2  4  3 25 22 24  6  8  9 16 11 26 17 15  1 18 20
```

When no additional arguments are provided, `sample(x)` just permutes the vector `x`. Above, the case originally picked is case 7, and the remaining elements of `picks` represent the cases picked subsequently.

To perform multiple simulations:

```
picks3 <- replicate(3, sample(cases))

##       [,1] [,2] [,3]
##  [1,]    1   12   21
##  [2,]   10    7   25
##  [3,]   21    2   11
##  [4,]    8    3   17
##  [5,]   11   25    9
##  [6,]   13   11    7
##  [7,]   25   14   16
##  [8,]    4    8    4
##  [9,]   15   17   13
## [10,]   12    5    3
## [11,]   24   19   19
## [12,]    2   18   23
## [13,]   22   10   20
## [14,]    6    4    1
## [15,]   20    6    8
## [16,]   23    9   10
## [17,]   14    1   12
## [18,]    5   16   24
## [19,]    9   23   14
## [20,]   16   26   15
## [21,]   26   21    5
## [22,]    3   24   22
## [23,]   17   15   26
## [24,]   19   22    2
## [25,]    7   13   18
## [26,]   18   20    6
```

Now, each column is an independent simulation of the pick order.

---

For interest, to simulate one pick at a time with a `for` loop (e.g. if you want to insert other steps in the process), you could do something like the following (though there are many ways to do it):

```
picks <- sample(cases, 1) # original pick
for (i in 2:length(cases)) { # subsequent picks
  remaining <- setdiff(cases, picks)
  picks[i] <- remaining[sample(length(remaining), 1)]
}
```

NB: we use `remaining[sample(length(remaining), 1)]` instead of just `sample(remaining, 1)` because at the last iteration, `remaining` will be a single number (the number of the last remaining case). Passing a single number, e.g. 4, to `sample` results in `sample(1:4, 1)` instead of the desired `sample(4, 1)`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13990125/489704) for more on that.