# Sample method error in r

Tags: r

I have a vector like that

```
objetosDisponibles <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

I choose random one with this

```
objetoAleatorio <- sample(objetosDisponibles,size = 1, replace = F)
```

Then, I delete the choosen element in the vector

```
objetosDisponibles <- objetosDisponibles[objetosDisponibles!=objetoAleatorio]
```

If I do this 4 times, I want to choose the elements ramdonly, when I used sample method at the vector with 1 element, it choose other diferent. You can probe this with this code:

```
cont <- 0
objetosDisponibles <- c(1,2,3,4)

while(cont < 4){

 objetoAleatorio <- sample(objetosDisponibles,size = 1, replace = F)
 print(objetoAleatorio)
 objetosDisponibles <-  objetosDisponibles[objetosDisponibles!=objetoAleatorio]
 print(objetosDisponibles)
 cont <- cont +1

}
```

*The error, a number with "L":*

[image]

*Print output:*

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990125/sampling-in-r-from-vector-of-varying-length Read the help page for `sample()`. It behaves differently when the first parameter has length 1.