# sample() in R unpredictable when vector length is one

Tags: r, random, sample

I am trying to debug a short program, and I get a disconcerting result towards the end of sampling from the elements of a vector under some conditions. It happens as the elements of the vector that remain draw down to a single value.

In the specific case I'm referring to the vector is called `remaining` and contains a single element, the number `2`. I would expect that any sampling of size 1 from this vector would stubbornly return `2`, since 2 is the only element in the vector, but this is not the case:

```
Browse[2]> is.vector(remaining)
[1] TRUE
Browse[2]> sample(remaining,1)
[1] 2
Browse[2]> sample(remaining,1)
[1] 2
Browse[2]> sample(remaining,1)
[1] 1
Browse[2]> sample(x=remaining, size=1)
[1] 1
Browse[2]> sample(x=remaining, size=1)
[1] 2
Browse[2]> sample(x=remaining, size=1)
[1] 1
Browse[2]> sample(x=remaining, size=1)
[1] 1
Browse[2]> sample(x=remaining, size=1)
[1] 1
```

As you can see, sometimes the return is `1` and some others, `2`.

What am I  misunderstanding about the function `sample()`?

Comment: `Browse[2]> all(remaining==2) [1] TRUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help("sample")`:

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1,
>   sampling via sample takes place from 1:x.

So, when you have `remaining = 2`, then `sample(remaining)` is equivalent to `sample(x = 1:2)`

#### Update

From the comments it's clear you are also looking for a way around this behavior. Here is a benchmark comparison of three mentioned alternatives:

```
library(microbenchmark)

# if remaining is of length one
remaining <- 2

microbenchmark(a = {if ( length(remaining) > 1 ) { sample(remaining) } else { remaining }},
               b = ifelse(length(remaining) > 1, sample(remaining), remaining),
               c = remaining[sample(length(remaining))])

Unit: nanoseconds
 expr  min   lq    mean median     uq   max neval cld
    a  349  489  625.12  628.0  663.5  3283   100 a  
    b 1536 1886 2240.58 2025.0 2165.5 13898   100  b 
    c 4051 4400 5193.41 4679.5 5064.0 38413   100   c

# If remaining is not of length one
remaining <- 1:10
microbenchmark(a = {if ( length(remaining) > 1 ) { sample(remaining) } else { remaining }},
               b = ifelse(length(remaining) > 1, sample(remaining), remaining),
               c = remaining[sample(length(remaining))])

Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval cld
    a  5.238  5.7970  6.82703  6.251  6.9145 51.264   100  a 
    b 11.663 12.2920 13.14831 12.851 13.3745 34.851   100   b
    c  5.238  5.9715  6.57140  6.426  6.8450 14.667   100  a
```

It looks like the suggestion from [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran) may be the fastest in your case if `sample()` is called much more often when `remaining` is of length > 1, and the `if() {} else {}` approach would be faster otherwise.

Comment: I read that, and I wasn't sure what it meant, or how to work around it.

Comment: You should check if remaining is length 1, and avoid sampling in that case.

Comment: @Toni This behavior is because sampling from a vector of length one is not meaningful; there is only one possible answer, which is the vector itself, not even some value derived from the vector.

Comment: @aocall That means an additional line or two in the code. There ought to be a way to work around this really messed up behaviour of the sample() function...

Comment: `x[sample(length(x),1)]`

Comment: `remaining <- c( 2, 2 )`

Comment: @Toni This is a very old "gotcha" that originates in R (or S, probably) trying to be _helpful_ for interactive work, allowing a shorter specification for the common case `sample(1:n)` as just `sample(n)`. Most people agree in hindsight it was ill-advised, but the behavior is so old now, and so much relies on that behavior that we're stuck with it.

Comment: @joran Would you advise placing then `sample` within and `ifelse()` statement? The issue is that `remainder` starts as a much longer vector within the loop, and it's only when it's withered down to 1 element that things start to go array...

Comment: @Toni Maybe something along the lines of `if ( length(remaining) > 1 ) { sample(remaining) } else { remaining }` since you won't need the vectorization and slow down of `ifelse()`

Comment: @Toni I would recommend something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990144/324364

Comment: `resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]` - see https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/19