# Why does sample() not work for a single number?

Tags: r

`sample(x,n)` The parameters are the vector, and how many times you wish to sample

```
sample(c(5,9),1) returns either 5 or 9
```

however,

```
sample(5,1) returns 1,2,3,4, or 5?
```

I've read the help section:

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1,
>   sampling via sample takes place from 1:x. Note that this convenience
>   feature may lead to undesired behaviour when x is of varying length in
>   calls such as sample(x). See the examples.

But is there a way to make it not do this? Or do I just need to include an if statement to avoid this.

Comment: you can use `sample(list(5), 1)` although that will give you a list answer. You might need to go to `sample(list(5), 1)[[1]]`

Comment: Probably duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13990125/324364

Comment: Thanks, I for some reason missed that in my initial search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or do I just need to include an if statement to avoid this.

Yeah, unfortunately. Something like this:

```
result = if(length(x) == 1) {x} else {sample(x, ...)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach: you simply subset a random value from your vector like this -

```
set.seed(4)

x <- c(5,9)
x[sample(length(x), 1)]
[1] 9

x <- 5
x[sample(length(x), 1)]
[1] 5
```

Comment: Thank you. Very clean solution.