# Function "sample" in R does not work properly

Tags: r, sample

I do not understand how the sample function is working if I have a vector as argument with only one element to sample from (and I just want to sample one element).

I am doing a simulation and me input vector `x` is going to be of different size every time my loop runs one step. But when the vector is containing only one element, for example `x = c(3)`, it should be sample 3, but I doesn't it starts to sample 2 and 1 all kind of numbers. I have tried to use `set.seed` and changed the replace argument, but something is wrong. Does anyone know what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: Please induce a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data rather than an image.

Answer (score 0):

From `?sample`:

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x. Note that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour when x is of varying length in calls such as sample(x).

So this behavior is expected if undesirable. A possible solution is in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990144) linked by user20650.